# Spring/Coil tool that will add pressure/force to support holding object in place

Tags: tools, mounting

I need a tool that will add pressure on a board to be able to support keep it in place. The design of the tool needs to allow other objects, the yellow board in this case, to wedge easily between the red board and the tool as shown below:

[image: ExampleA] [image: ExampleB]

The red board has the black hook attached to it. We then need to drop it onto the yellow board like in the picture. I'm looking for something along the lines of the second drawing, where the coil/spring pushes against it.

I'm also open to any other tool that can accomplish this

Answer (score 2):

Use wooden shims.  You can use two of them (pointing opposite directions) to get a nice flat surface, and if they are not thick enough on their own, use more scrap wood to tighten the gap.

This solution is easy to tap into place and later remove with a small hammer, will give you as little or as much clamping as you need.

If you need to move this item around a lot, just glue one shim in place (on the metal), so install and removal can be done with one hand.

Comment: Upvote because this is one viable option, specially since we can in fact glue one shim to the metal. However we do have to move it frequently, which is the reason I'd like for the solution to be able to let me install/remove the setup quick